# Calculate the balance; it only gives one balance

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to get the balance for each transaction but it only prints `2329.26`.

[image]

It should print like this:

```
Withdrawal    Income    Balance
              2 000     2 500
500                     500
              1 000     1 000
```

SQL

```
SELECT t1.*,
       SUM(t2.data_sum) AS sum

FROM transactions AS t1
INNER JOIN transactions AS t2

ON t1.datetime_completed >= t2.datetime_completed
AND t1.id_user >= t2.id_user
AND t1.id_account >= t2.id_account

GROUP BY t1.id_account, t1.id_user, t1.datetime_completed, t1.data_sum
ORDER BY t1.datetime_completed
```

Database

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_account` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_user` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`data_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`data_sum` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`data_note` text NOT NULL,
`data_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`is_payed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`is_completed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`datetime_completed` datetime NOT NULL
```

[image]

I want it to count from bottom and up, so the oldest transaction are on the bottom.

How should the SQL looks like, to make it calculate the correct balance?

Comment: I have updated the "It should prints like this". I have a cold today so my head is not exactly with me. The balance is now right for this part of my question

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: @ChrisAlbert I'm using the latest version of XAMPP, so it should be 5.0.11

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your datetimes aren't identical? Unless they have different time portions, you'll have them all tallying at the same time.

Comment: @SQLTactics Just for the test columns, my dates and times are not identical. However, I have other transactions that I have hidden for this question and those have no times at all, just dates and many of them have the same date. I want to have the freedom of choose if I want to add the time or not to my transactions and still calculate the correct balance

Comment: Would help to see the data dump of the `transactions` table for these three transactions to better understand what your code is doing... (can't tell whether `id_user` and `id_account` increment, etc.) Can you add it in?

Comment: Sure :) I have added the data dump picture for the test columns to my question now. `id_account` and `id_user` can have the same value.

Comment: how can you `give the freedom to not add time to transaction` and at the same time calculate balance correctly?? There is no balance on the time line if there is no time... Also why do you compare `id_user` and `id_account` with `>=` if you only need to filter out one user in one account? With such clause you grab transactions from multiple users and accounts

Comment: This executes differently in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9e8b/1

Comment: @SQLTactics Hm. That's very weird. I deleted all the other transactions besides of those in the picture I added, copied the SQL query from SQL Fiddle and pasted it into my code. Now the balance only shows `1000.00` on all transactions.

Comment: I got it working now! The SQL query was **outside** the loop so I moved the query into the loop and added `WHERE t1.id = :idtransaction` and now the balance are correct for all the transaction. I really hate to be cold sometimes -.- Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there I think you'll find your answer [HERE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94545/calculate-row-value-based-on-previous-and-actual-row-values)

Also I created [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16ba78/2) for your example so you can see how it work.

Here is query:

```
SELECT t1.completed, t1.name, 
       CASE WHEN t1.data_sum < 0 THEN ABS(t1.data_sum) ELSE 0.00 END AS wihtdrawl,
        CASE WHEN t1.data_sum > 0 THEN t1.data_sum ELSE 0.00 END AS income,
        @b := @b + t1.data_sum AS balance
 FROM (SELECT @b := 0) AS bal
 CROSS JOIN myTable AS t1
 ORDER BY t1.id;
```

GL!

Comment: Many thanks for the better SQL query :) I have one problem though. In phpMyAdmin, `balance` shows the correct balance but on my website, it shows only `1000.00` for the first one, and then `-500` and `2000` for the other two. I'm fetching `withdrawl` and `income` from `$balance['withdrawl']` and `$balance['income']` but `$balance['balance']` gives me the value I already mentioned. Do you have any ideas of why this happens?

Comment: @ErikEdgren weird, it sounds like it doesn't use previous row in calculation of balance. Like it's just assign value of data_sum to variable like @b := t1.data_sum instead of to calculate balance using previous value stored in variable (like in example @b := @b + t1.data_sum), it simply return value of data_sum in balance without calculation, but I really don't know why it's happened, it should be tested to see where is the problem. As you said query works fine in phpMyAdmin also in Fiddle...

Comment: Yeah. It's weird. I have the query within a loop that loops all of the transactions of the account. And then I have added this line between `CROSS JOIN` and `ORDER BY`: `WHERE t1.id = :idtransaction` where `:idtransaction` is the id of the transaction from the loop. How can I test the query to see where the problem is?

Comment: @ErikEdgren well it would be good thing if I could see what you added to the query maybe I see something you didn't, you know fresh pair of eyes in case like this is always a good thing. I don't know how to explain you how to test query or something, i just go through the step by step I try to figure out where it's stop wrong as expected, in which part doesn't give expected result...

Comment: That's so true :) Many thanks for you want to help me figure this out :) Here's the whole code: http://pastebin.com/FKF6nrEZ (expires after 1 week from now). Pastebin seems to have some problems with the stylesheet and JavaScript though...

Comment: I replaced the query for `$get_transactions` with your query and now it works. But as it is now, it only sorts the oldest on top and the newest at the bottom (like if you have `datetime_completed` as `ASC` instead of `DESC`). How can I reverse the order? Here's the new query: http://pastebin.com/zGg8aGJh

Comment: @ErikEdgren Well if I understand you correctly, in ORDER BY clause you just should add DESC after t1.id - should be ORDER BY t1.id DESC Look [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16ba78/10)

Comment: Yes, but then we come back to the problem we had at first (read my first comment for your answer) :/

Comment: @ErikEdgren oh didn't understand thought you figure that out :), I take a look at your query here is the problem (I think) when you call my query for each $get_transactions basically you do something like [THIS](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16ba78/12) and the query simply can't do calculation based on previous row because you select one row for each iteration... you should place my query into $get_transaction (little modified) and echo result from there don't use $balance. query should look something like [THIS](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16ba78/14) **Fiddle don't work because it's different table**

Comment: Many thanks but the problem is still there :/ If I change `ORDER BY t1.id DESC` to `ORDER BY t1.id ASC` it works as well for `ORDER BY t1.id`. It's like if `t1.id DESC` is not allowed or just ignored. If there is an error, you'll get an error message, of course, but what's wrong? :/ I have just replaced the query for `$get_transactions` with your code in your last link and changed some things so it will be right for the website.

Comment: @ErikEdgren huh I don't have a clue what could make a problem in simple order by clause, I can't figure it out... I'm little confused by that it's just simplest ORDER BY... Maybe you could ask new question about that, and maybe someone will see what we are missing..

Comment: Me neither :( Yeah. I will do that some day :) Many thanks for your help. I really appreciated it

Comment: @ErikEdgren You're welcome... I hope I can be more helpful next time. GL